# nftables destination nat block local access to port

Tags: nftables

I have set up nftables on my server and I want to redirect all traffic coming in to certain protected ports (e.g. 80) to be redirected to a higher port which is available without root permissions (e.g. 13080). I want to be able to access only 80 remotely but both ports locally.
This is the setup I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet firewall {

    chain inbound {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;

        ct status dnat counter accept # accept everything that came through destination nat (port 80)

        iifname lo counter accept
        oifname lo counter accept

        ct state { established, related } counter accept
        ct state invalid counter drop

        tcp dport 22 ct state new counter accept

        counter reject with icmpx type port-unreachable # reject everything else
    }

    chain destination-nat {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept
        tcp dport 80 counter redirect to 13080 # redirect 80 to 13080
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
    }

    chain outbound {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }
}
```

However, this blocks local access to port 80 for some reason (13080 is still accessible though). Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample of the [Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) which stays valid for *nftables*:

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]

There's an important detail written: *** "nat" table only consulted for "NEW" connections**.

For a locally initiated connection, the first packet of the new connection creates a NEW conntrack state during output (the output's conntrack box). When this connection is looped back (in almost all cases through the *lo* interface) this *same* conntrack state is matched when the packet comes back through prerouting (the other conntrack box): there aren't two conntrack states for a local looped back connection.

For other cases the first packet of a new connection arrives through prerouting (the prerouting's conntrack box) and leads to the creation of a NEW conntrack state.

So when the first looped-back packet of the connection is sent, a NEW conntrack entry is created *during output* and when this packet arrives back through prerouting it's matching an existing conntrack entry: not a NEW state anymore. NAT hooks (that means the nat/prerouting chain `destination-nat`) won't be traversed and thus can't affect this connection: the opportunity was missed during the output step.

Instead, using the *dnat* statement in nat/output where there will be a NEW conntrack state will solve this case. As it would by default affect any locally initiated connection (ie even to Internet), care must be taken to only use it for connections that stay local: through the *lo* interface. This chain and rule will do that:

```
nft add chain inet firewall loopback-nat '{ type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept; }'
nft add rule inet firewall loopback-nat oif lo tcp dport 80 counter redirect to :13080
```

You can follow the behaviour simply by running elsewhere the [`conntrack`](https://manpages.debian.org/conntrack/conntrack.8#DESCRIPTION) command in event mode:

```
conntrack -E -p tcp --dport 80
```

and see the difference for a connection initiated from outside and a locally initiated looped-back one, with or without this additional chain. Remember that the *nat* hook will have seen only entries displayed with the `[NEW]` state (and will already have altered accordingly the entry displayed by the command).